# Почему нельзя использовать фиксированно заданные шрифты?

Tags: html, css

Привет. 
Перечитал информацию о шрифтах, и для меня это одна из наболевших непонятных тем верстки, связанная с нехваткой достойной, доступной и четкой информации.

Подскажите, почему нежелательно использовать фиксированые шрифты?

Первым и главным аргументом было отсутствие масштабирования фиксированных шрифтов в старых IE. Если брать IE8+, то этот аргумент не есть актуальным.

Второй аргумент - при масштабировании блока текст может вылазить за его пределы. Это особо видно в резиновых блоках при ресайзе окна браузера, когда текст длинный вылазит за пределы блока.
Аргумент очень веский, но можно использовать мощь media queries - переопределить шрифт при малых расширениях.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 280px) {
   div{font-size:12px}
 }
```

Третий аргумент - это удобство масштабирования страниц. Если задан базовый шрифт, от которого отталкиваются размеры дочерних блоков, то достаточно изменить размер шрифта родителя, и тогда пропорционально изменятся шрифты везде.   
Это также актуально для адаптивного дизайна, где для малых экранов, просто увеличив размер шрифта, мы получим читабельный текст.

Просьба подсказать еще информацию по поводу целесобразности использования фиксированных шрифтов. И верны ли мои выводы, которые сделал на основе статей? Может, я не прав...

Comment: `при масштабировании блока текст может вылазить за его пределы`

В css есть параметр переноса слов, прописав который, вылазить ничего не будет :) если только слово не длинней ширины окна либо блока.

Comment: Еще один плюс против использования  ...спасибо

Comment: Не понял, как второй аргумент связан с размером шрифта в пикселях. Изменение ширины экрана / ширины родителя никак не повляет ни на пиксели, ни на em`ы, ни на проценты. Краем глаза, правда, видел единицу REM, но это мы еще не проходили :)

Аргумент номер три актуален только в случае с адаптивным дизайном. Да и то не в таком глобальном масштабе, как вы пишете, мол, базовый размер поменял, и все поменялось. В таком случае у вас весь сайт должен пропорционально увеличиваться/уменьшаться. В более локальных масштабах, это может иметь смысл.

Comment: В остальных же случаях, что с font-size, что с line-height, это головная боль делить 17 на 13 на калькуляторе, округлять и прописывать в коде. Если вы задаете эти размеры относительными, то, по идее, и всякие padding'и, margin'ы нужно так же задавать относительными, и в итоге у вас весь сайт становится "относительным", и непонятно зачем. В итоге, даже если вы решите поменять базовый размер шрифта на уже готовом сайте, у вас будут куда большие проблемы, чем пиксели.